# Detect call's offset with ptrace

Tags: c, assembly, function-calls, ptrace

I'm trying to do a program that can detect calls with the function ptrace.
Using PTRACE_SINGLESTEP I can run a program instructions by instructions, then, when I get the OP_CODE 0xe8 pointed by the register RIP, I use PTRACE_PEEKTEXT to get the 4 next bytes after the adress pointed by RIP.
Then, according to the documentation that I found on internet, the 4 bytes coutains an offset referring to the location to jump.
It seems like PTRACE_PEEKTEXT is returning some weird values, and I get offsets too big.
Here my code below:

```
  instr_num = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, this->pid, regs.rip, 0);
  dest = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, this->pid, regs.rip + 1, 0);
  if (instr_num == 0xe8)
    {
      printf("call : %ld\n", regs.rip + dest);
    }
```

And here's the output:

```
call : -2853719444197214464
call : -2853719444197214464
call : -2853719444197214464
```

And this is the objdump -D output, and as you can see there is 15 bytes of offset between the call from the main and the beginning of the function func:

```
00000000004004c4 <func>:
4004c4:       55                      push   %rbp
4004c5:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
4004c8:       5d                      pop    %rbp
4004c9:       c3                      retq   

00000000004004ca <main>:
4004ca:       55                      push   %rbp
4004cb:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
4004ce:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
4004d3:       e8 ec ff ff ff          callq  4004c4 <func>
4004d8:       5d                      pop    %rbp
4004d9:       c3                      retq
```

If just after I detected a call, I do a ptrace(PTRACE_SINGLESTEP) once, will my RIP contain the adress of the function I just jumped to ? According to my tests it seems not to, but I think it should.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
printf("call : 0x%lx\n", regs.rip + (long) (int) (dest & (unsigned long) UINT_MAX);
```

`dest` is a 64-bit value but the offset is encoded here on 32 bits.  Printing in hex is much nicer for this kind of code

Comment: Actually it's a signed offset.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky Yeah I realized that.  I was just trying to avoid implementation defined behavior and forgot the casts.  Edited.  Thanks